# Can i connect my company's SQL server with python and pull data

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to connect my company's SQL database with python to pull the data and paste it in a dataframe. Is it possible. could you please help me with sample code

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really a SQL _language_ related issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much detail in your question, so I will tell the steps.

1. You will need to install a driver or a module (like `pyodbc` or `mysql-sql-connector-python`). This is to help python app interact with an SQL application.
2. Now you will have to create an instance of connection with appropriate login credentials and the database name you want to connect to.
3. Finally you can read the data onto dataframe directly by using `pandas.read_sql(query, conn)`.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-pandas?view=sql-server-ver16) I hope will help you with sample snippet and more details